Identify this bouncing ball screensaver in DOS
This is an odd ask, but I remember using a DOS TSR screensaver long ago that I've been trying to find without luck. I've dug through shareware archives and never found it. Perhaps someone knows what it is.
It was really simple, just a white ball, or a circle really, that bounced off each side of the screen at a 90 degree angle. It was activated after a timeout or by pressing CtrlZ.
I first saw it in the early 90s on the computers in school but no idea where the teacher obtained it.

This sounds like Michael J. Mefford’s CONCEAL, published in PC Magazine. It provides some measure of file protection (by allowing files to be marked as system files, and protecting their attributes), and (optionally password-protected) screen blanking.
The screen blanking function can display a bouncing ball instead of only blanking the display. It can be configured to blank the screen after a timeout, and can be invoked manually using AltZ (the hotkey is configurable). If you have access to PC Magazine utility archives, it’s available in v9n15.zip.


You are amazing! I would have never found that. I can't say for certain this was exactly the same program, but "conceal" sounds vaguely familiar to me so perhaps it is.
